# Corresponding morphism of an adèlic point

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth geometrically connected variety over a number field $k$ and let $X(\mathbb{A}_k)$ be the space of adèlic points of $X$, i.e., for some finite set $S$ containing the infinite places of $k$ we can find smooth model $\mathcal{X}$ of finite type over $\mathcal{O}_S$ such that $X = \mathcal{X} \times _{\mathcal{O}_S} k$ and
$$X(\mathbb{A}_k) = \prod_{v \in S}X(k_v) \times \prod_{v \notin S}\mathcal{X}(\mathcal{O}_v).$$

For an adèlic point $(P_v)_v \in X(\mathbb{A}_k)$, how is the corresponding morphism $\mathrm{Spec}\, \mathbb{A}_k \rightarrow X$ defined? For example, if $t \in X(k)$, then $t$ embeds as $(t)_v \in X(\mathbb{A}_k)$ and so the corresponding morphism is given by $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{A}_k \rightarrow \{t\} \subset X$. But if $(P_v)_v$ is a general point not coming from a $k$-rational point, is there any way we can describe the corresponding morphism?

More specifically, are there general sufficient conditions in determining if, given a fixed adèlic point $(P_v)_v$, a particular closed point $t \in X$ is not in the image of the corresponding morphism $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{A}_k \rightarrow X$?